# Android: WebView Scrolling not working properly inside Vertical Directional Viewpager

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I have a Vertical Viewpager (Directional Viewpager) . Viewpager Contains two Fragments . Above fragment is videoView and Below Fragment contains the WebView.
Webview content exceeds the page limit .Hence nested Scrolling occurs .I could move from videoView to webView by scrolling down. but when I try to go to previous videoview from webview I could not scroll back because WebView Scroll is enabled .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scroll up to switch to VideoView check if webview scroll has reached to 0. if yes switch it pro-grammatically using `v.setCurrentItem(item)` method.

Example:

```
webview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged()
    {
    if(v.getScrollY() < offset)
    {
        // change viewpager selection
    }
    }
});
```

offset is range of up scroll limit of webview.